# Factoring an Equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been using the quadratic equation to factor $2z^2+5iz-2$. Obviously the roots are $z=-2i$ and $z=-i/2$.

Why can't I then write it out as $(z+2i)(z+i/2)$ which is not equivalent to the initial function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If a quadratic has roots $r,s$ then all you know is that it equals $c(x-r)(x-s)$ for some constant $c$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it out as $2(z+2i)(z+\frac{i}{2})$. See lulu's comment.

Answer (score 0):

If a quadratic equation has roots $ x_1 $ and $ x_2 $ then it can be expressed as: 
$$ c(x-x_1)(x - x_2) $$

For instance, $ x^2 + 5x + 6 $ has the same solution as  $ 5x^2 + 25x + 30 $ . 
So multiplying by a constant term does not affect the roots of the equation. Here, if you multiply $ (z+2i)(z+i/2) $ by 2, then you get your original function.